# get jsonObject from ajax deferred response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, deferred

I am sending an item to a SharePoint list using Ajax, after this is done I want to push the jsonObject I get in response to a list of items.

in AppController.js

```
   $scope.addListItem = function(listItem){
    $.when(SharePointJSOMService.addListItem($scope, ListName, listItem))
        .done(function (jsonObject) {

            //$scope.items.push(jsonObject);

            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }

        })

        .fail(function (err) {
            console.info(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
};
```

Ajax call

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: restQueryUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(listItem),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
```

I hope this is enough information for you to be able to help me.
Basically what I need to know is how to reach the data I get in return from the ajax call

Comment: You can access data in the succes function like an object. Just use data.somevar (note the dot) to access the variables of the object. You can view the object in your console with console.log(data). But what you should do is remove the ajax and replace it with angulars  $http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: ye, I can use '(JSON.parse(data.d.ID))' to get the ID of the object, but that's not enough, should I do that for all attributes? Seems like a bad way to do it. I will look into the $hhtp

Comment: Why can't I pass the whole object in the 'resolve' function? I am only able to pass the ID attribute, like so: (JSON.parse(data.d.ID))

Answer (score 0):

No worries, I figured it out. I was caught up in using the 'JSON.parse' method, when in reality all I had to do was:

```
var id = data.d.ID;
var created = data.d.Created;

deferred.resolve(id, created);
```

I guess I have to create a new 'var' for each attribute I want to pass in the resolve method, but that's fine